# How do you integrate activity feeds between Lync and SharePoint

Tags: my-site, activity-feed

How do you integrate the My Activities feed on Lync, with the SharePoint My Newsfeed feed on SharePoint 2010?

As an added bonus, how can these activity updates be surfaced in Outlook?

Are their any Projects to publish between the different products, as I don't believe they provide this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime ago, I've created a [blog post](http://www.avanadeblog.com/sharepointasg/2010/06/synchronizing-your-ocs-status-with-your-sharepoint-2010-mysite-status.html): How to sync the OCS/Lync status with the SharePoint MySite. Maybe you can use this as a starting point.